# Keep tracking number of calls and comparison in a recursive merge sort

Tags: python, sorting, recursion, parameters

I am trying to keep track of the number of calls to merge_sort() and total comparison during merge() WITHOUT using global variables. My code below correctly counts the number of calls and comparison. How should I do without using global variables?

```
import numpy as np

call = 0
compare = 0


def merge_sort(array):
    global call   # update global
    call += 1
    
    n = len(array)
    if n <= 1:
        return array

    arr1 = merge_sort(array[0:n // 2])
    arr2 = merge_sort(array[n // 2:n])

    
    new_arr = merge(arr1, arr2)

    return new_arr


def merge(arr1, arr2):
    new_arr = np.empty(len(arr1) + len(arr2), dtype=int)
    ind = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    com_num = 0   # Count comparisons in this call
    while i < len(arr1) and j < len(arr2):
        if arr1[i] < arr2[j]:
            com_num += 1   # +1
            new_arr[ind] = arr1[i]
            i += 1
            ind += 1
        else:
            com_num += 1   # +1
            new_arr[ind] = arr2[j]
            j += 1
            ind += 1

    while i < len(arr1):
        new_arr[ind] = arr1[i]
        i += 1
        ind += 1

    while j < len(arr2):
        new_arr[ind] = arr2[j]
        j += 1
        ind += 1

    global compare    # update global
    compare += com_num

    return new_arr
```

Comment: Try **decorator**, maybe?

Comment: Does this mean using another function to warp these 2 up and make count and compare within it? I think this still uses global variables?

Comment: send and receive values as extra variables `merge_sort(array, call, compare)` and `return result, call, compare`. OR convert to classes and you will have class variables instead of global variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
def merge_sort(array):
    '''Performs merge sort on a given array, and outputs number of
       calls and comparisons.'''

    sorted_array, calls, comps = _merge_sort(array, 0, 0)
    print("Made %d calls and %d comparisons." % (calls, comps))
    return(sorted_array)


def _merge_sort(array, calls, comps):
    calls += 1
    n = len(array)

    # Empty or singleton arrays are sorted by definition.
    if n <= 1:
        return (array, calls, comps)
    # Otherwise we recursively merge sort.
    else:
        left_array, calls, comps  = _merge_sort(array[:n//2], calls, comps)
        right_array, calls, comps = _merge_sort(array[n//2:], calls, comps)
        sorted_array, comps = _merge(left_array, right_array, comps)

    return (sorted_array, calls, comps)


def _merge(arr1, arr2, comps):
    '''Merges two sorted lists into a bigger sorted list.'''
    # NOTE: You can do this with bisect.insort, but I'm assuming you want to
    # write your own "first-principles" algorithm, so I didn't use that.

    output_array = []
    arr1_len = len(arr1)
    arr2_len = len(arr2)

    # Merge the lists by comparing elements.
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < arr1_len and j < arr2_len:
        comps += 1
        if arr1[i] < arr2[j]:
            output_array.append(arr1[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            output_array.append(arr2[j])
            j += 1

    # One of the lists will now have been exhausted, so we can append
    # whatever remains.
    output_array += arr1[i:] + arr2[j:]

    return (output_array, comps)
```

Here I use two "private" methods that start with an underscore. This is quite standard when working with recursion that requires the tracking of an internal variable between calls, so at to avoid having the user of the function supply these.

I also didn't use NumPy here, just to make it as general as possible. You can go in and put it where you think it's appropriate. Furthermore I did some general code cleaning. In particular, see the note at the start of the `_merge` function.